# How to initialize various data type members values from different classes?

Tags: java, android, object-oriented-analysis

I have a public class named as ABC. There are various types of variables declared with the getter and setter method along with that.

Those values will be coming from various other classes.

What will be the best approach to initialize those data types?

I can go with making that class as singleton.I don't want to create multiple object for that class.

The values which will be coming from classes are B,C,D,E.

If i create a singleton object in B and pass that with the Intent to C,D,E and assign remaining values will that be the best approach ?

OR

creating a public static object as a constant.and access that object from different classes and store variable.

OR

is there any other better approach ?

Please advice.
[Please Note: Coding is for Android]

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the singleton approach

```
public class ABC
{
    private static ABC instance;

    private String memberVar;

    private ABC()

    public static ABC getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ABC();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Then you can access it from the other classes via ABC.getInstance().yourGetter()

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.How to forcefully garbage collect that object ? that Static part i personally don't like.For a static reference don't you think it can create some problems?

Comment: Static references exist in the scope of your app. So if your app is closed/removed it also frees up the static resources. Do you have any concrete pointers why that should cause problems? I am using such a static singleton for example as the storage mechanism for my app and I don't see any issues.

Comment: Suppose i move on to activity C.i store some values from Activity B.Now i come back to B from C.again come back from B.Open B again.i will get previous stored value in this step.I don't want that.I have to manually free my static reference then.

Comment: I am not aware of a mechanism to share data between activities and where the lifecycle is bound to the activities. What you could do is to store the member data in the Activity and then use fragments instead. Just an idea though without knowing your concrete use case.